# how to give functionality to menu button

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i need is when ever i click menu button (means iphones menu button not application button) of the iphone it will display two options like about and help when  i click help it display some text and when i click about it display some web how can i done this. pls post some code thank u .

Comment: If you mean the home button, you can't override the functionality of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a complete introduction to writing iPhone apps, not just a solution to this one specific problem.

Go read [Apple's Getting Started](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started) documentation for iPhone development.

Comment: yeah, I don't understand what "menu button" means:))